# What was with Miles Morales's stickers?

Tags: plot-explanation, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse*, Miles Morales applied some stickers on public places and even near the end he uses his powers to apply the sticker on a place where his dad can't find it.

But why? What are these stickers and what is their significance for him or the story?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Miles is a graffiti artist

We can see this in the first minutes of the movie when he is doodling in these name tag stickers and putting them around the neighborhood, this pisses off his dad because he is a police officer and graffiti [is illegal in New York](https://www.gjllp.com/news/understanding-the-law-of-making-graffiti-in-new-york-part-1/).

Miles is also a kid, who doesn't have money and permission to buy real paint to paint real graffiti, that's why he uses these stickers.

[image: miles]

This is paid off later when uncle Aron takes Miles to a place to paint a full mural with real spray paint.

And also as @OrageDog pointed out, [Sticker art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticker_art) is a form of street art:

> Sticker art (also known as sticker bombing, sticker slapping, slap tagging, and sticker tagging) is a form of street art in which an image or message is publicly displayed using stickers. These stickers may promote a political agenda, comment on a policy or issue, or comprise a subcategory of graffiti.

Comment: His dad is annoyed because [it's illegal](https://www.gjllp.com/news/understanding-the-law-of-making-graffiti-in-new-york-part-1/).

Comment: see also [Wikipedia - Sticker art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticker_art)